# Using Copy command in ARM template with properties that repeat and some that do not

Tags: azure-rm-template

I'm creating an ARM template that has rules for FTP traffic.  I'd like to use the copy command within the probes property of the load balancer to create probes for a range of ports, but I also have other probes that do not need to be repeated (fall outside of the copy).  When I try to add both, the ARM template says it's invalid because the probes property is already present.  Is it possible to use the "copy" syntax in addition to other value or must the "copy" be the only ARM syntax that builds the entire list of array values?

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard",
    "tier": "Regional"
  },
  "name": "[variables('lb-csl-private.name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "scale": null,
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
        "properties": {
          "privateIPAddress": "[variables('ip-lb-csl-private')]",
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnet-csl.name'), variables('vnet-csl.subnets.loadBalancerName'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "probes",
        "count": 10,
        "input": {
          "name": "[concat('probe-CSL-PASV-', copyIndex('probes'))]",
          "properties": {
            "protocol": "Tcp",
            "port": "[copyIndex('probes')]",
            "inervalInSeconds": 5,
            "numberOfProbes": 2
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "probes": [
      {
        "name": "probe-CSL-FTP",
        "properties": {
          "protocol": "Tcp",
          "port": 21,
          "intervalInSeconds": 5,
          "numberOfProbes": 2
        }
      }
    ],
    "inboundNatRules": [],
    "outboundRules": [],
    "inboundNatPools": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to do that using variables:

```
"variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "probes",
        "count": 10,
        "input": {
          "name": "[concat('probe-CSL-PASV-', copyIndex('probes'))]",
          "properties": {
            "protocol": "Tcp",
            "port": "[copyIndex('probes')]",
            "inervalInSeconds": 5,
            "numberOfProbes": 2
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "otherProbes": [
        {
             probe1
        },
        {
             probe2
        },
        etc
    ]
}
```

and then, in your load balancer:

```
"probes": "[concat(variables('probes'), variables('otherProbes'))]"
```